# Simple regex for EU VAT-numbers

Tags: regex

I need a regex for validating EU-VAT numbers. There are some out there, but they are all specific to each member state and I do not need it to be so specific. So something that requires the user to enter a certain length of characters with first ones required to be letters, and rest digits with some letters allowed is good enough.

So essentially I need to match following

- 2-4 first characters must be letters
- The rest can either be digits only, or contain max 2 letters among the digits
- Ignore hyphens (some member states use them)
- Ignore spaces and underscores (because users)

So far I have the following, which kind of does the job, but unfortunately also matches input with only letters (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP) [link](https://regex101.com/r/KFME3H/2)

```
([A-Za-z]{2,4})([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_ ]{2,12})
```

Here you can see the format of all the VAT numbers.
https://www.gov.uk/guidance/vat-eu-country-codes-vat-numbers-and-vat-in-other-languages

Comment: So, what is the requirement? At least 1 digit and at least 1 letter after the first 2 to 4 letters? Or at least 1 hyphen? Or underscore?

Comment: Your example `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP` matches the rules you posted. So to clarify: you need the last portion (2-12 characters) to contain at least 1 number and least 1 letter, so that it isn't all numbers or all letters?

Comment: First 2-4 letters, rest alphanumeric up to 12.

Comment: @Strikegently, yes correct.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no hyphens, no underscores and no spaces. As I said some member states use hyphens, the others might be entered by users for whatever reason.

Comment: Why is the input with only letters bad for you then? There are *no hyphens, no underscores and no spaces*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you have a look at the link I posted in the question, some VAT-numbers have a letter among the numbers, but none consist of only letters.

Comment: Ok, I see "yes, correct". Than try `^[A-Za-z]{2,4}(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{2,12}$`

Comment: First 2-4 are letters, the rest can be either only digits or contain max 2 letters among the digits. No VAT-number is only letters.

Comment: Please update the question with these actual requirements. Although [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/S0REZ0/1/) seems to comply with the latest requirement update, it does not seem to match those numbers on the Web page. Please check and let know.

Comment: Could you please provide some test cases to see if the pattern works for you or not?

Comment: Unfortunately does not match the test strings here (I've added some example VAT-numbers)
[link](https://regex101.com/r/EHs7LP/1)

Comment: @S.Weckström:  I forgot to add spaces, `_` and `-` into the regex pattern and you forgot to add `m` modifier when testing at regex101.com. I explained the updated pattern in my answer below.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Awesome, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
^[A-Za-z]{2,4}(?=.{2,12}$)[-_\s0-9]*(?:[a-zA-Z][-_\s0-9]*){0,2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lhR5lJ/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z]{2,4}` - 2 to 4 ASCII letters
- `(?=.{2,12}$)` - then, there must be 2 to 12 chars up to the end  of the string (it does not matter much what chars, we are just checking the length of the rest of the string here)
- `[-_\s0-9]*` - zero or more digits, `-`, `_` or whitespace
- `(?:[a-zA-Z][-_ 0-9]*){0,2}` - 0 to 2 consecutive sequences of:

  - `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
  - `[-_\s0-9]*` -  zero or more digits, `-`, `_` or whitespace
- `$` - end of string,

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note: there might be other "freaky" inputs, like [`CNTR--------`, or `CNTR_________`](https://regex101.com/r/9tL0Ui/1), etc. You might want to make the pattern more precise, [like this one](https://regex101.com/r/9tL0Ui/2).

Comment: May I ask how inputs like that would get there?

Comment: @S.Weckström Ask the users, not me :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a python module to verify VAT number. It internally have series of regexes. I have been using it personally and it is very accurate. You may want to check it out : https://pypi.org/project/vatnumber/