# Python regex to find EU VAT numbers in HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I am trying to find EU VAT numbers from HTML code using a regex.

I have tried regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46405400/8771126) and [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s21.html) but it does not work properly

Using scrapy shell with an example :

```
scrapy shell https://www.petch.fr/policies/legal-notice
```

Directly from Python shell :

```
import re
html = response.text
vat_regex1 = re.compile(r"^[A-Za-z]{2,4}(?=.{2,12}$)[-_\s0-9]*(?:[a-zA-Z][-_\s0-9]*){0,2}$")
vat_regex2  = re.compile(r"""^(
                (AT)?U[0-9]{8} |                              # Austria
                (BE)?0[0-9]{9} |                              # Belgium
                (BG)?[0-9]{9,10} |                            # Bulgaria
                (CY)?[0-9]{8}L |                              # Cyprus
                (CZ)?[0-9]{8,10} |                            # Czech Republic
                (DE)?[0-9]{9} |                               # Germany
                (DK)?[0-9]{8} |                               # Denmark
                (EE)?[0-9]{9} |                               # Estonia
                (EL|GR)?[0-9]{9} |                            # Greece
                (ES)?[0-9A-Z][0-9]{7}[0-9A-Z] |               # Spain
                (FI)?[0-9]{8} |                               # Finland
                (FR)?[0-9A-Z]{2}[0-9]{9} |                    # France
                (GB)?([0-9]{9}([0-9]{3})?|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}) | # United Kingdom
                (HU)?[0-9]{8} |                               # Hungary
                (IE)?[0-9]S[0-9]{5}L |                        # Ireland
                (IT)?[0-9]{11} |                              # Italy
                (LT)?([0-9]{9}|[0-9]{12}) |                   # Lithuania
                (LU)?[0-9]{8} |                               # Luxembourg
                (LV)?[0-9]{11} |                              # Latvia
                (MT)?[0-9]{8} |                               # Malta
                (NL)?[0-9]{9}B[0-9]{2} |                      # Netherlands
                (PL)?[0-9]{10} |                              # Poland
                (PT)?[0-9]{9} |                               # Portugal
                (RO)?[0-9]{2,10} |                            # Romania
                (SE)?[0-9]{12} |                              # Sweden
                (SI)?[0-9]{8} |                               # Slovenia
                (SK)?[0-9]{10}                                # Slovakia
            )$""")
```

Check on target :

```
>>> 'FR79852457621' in html
True
```

Regex 1 tests :

```
>>> vat_regex1.findall('FR79852457621')
['FR79852457621']
>>> vat_regex1.findall(' FR79852457621 ')
[]
>>> vat_regex1.findall(html)
[]
```

Regex 2 tests :

```
>>> vat_regex2.findall('FR79852457621')
[]
>>> vat_regex2.findall(' FR79852457621 ')
[]
>>> vat_regex2.findall(html)
[]
```

I am trying to modify the *vat_regex1* but still couldn't find the good expression. The closer I can get to right now, testing only for a FRANCE VAT number format:

```
>>> vat_regex3 = re.compile(r"(?:[A-Za-z]{2,4}(?=.{2,12}$)[-_0-9]*(?:[a-zA-Z][-_0-9]*){0,2}?)")
>>> vat_regex3.findall('FR79852457621')
['FR79852457621']
>>> vat_regex3.findall(' FR79852457621 ')
['FR79852457621']
>>> vat_regex2.findall(html)
[]
```

What regex would do the trick to find all EU VAT numbers in HTML code (there might be cases where there are some whitespaces) ?

Here you can see the format of all the VAT numbers. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/vat-eu-country-codes-vat-numbers-and-vat-in-other-languages

**#### Edit**
Minimal reproductible example :

```
import requests
import re

regex = re.compile(
        r"""\b(
                    (?:AT)U[0-9]{8}|                              # Austria
                    (?:BE)0[0-9]{9}|                              # Belgium
                    (?:BG)[0-9]{9,10}|                            # Bulgaria
                    (?:CY)[0-9]{8}L|                              # Cyprus
                    (?:CZ)[0-9]{8,10}|                            # Czech Republic
                    (?:DE)[0-9]{9}|                               # Germany
                    (?:DK)[0-9]{8}|                               # Denmark
                    (?:EE)[0-9]{9}|                               # Estonia
                    (?:EL|GR)[0-9]{9}|                            # Greece
                    (?:ES)[0-9A-Z][0-9]{7}[0-9A-Z]|               # Spain
                    (?:FI)[0-9]{8}|                               # Finland
                    (?:FR)[0-9A-Z]{2}[0-9]{9}|                    # France
                    (?:GB)(?:[0-9]{9}(?:[0-9]{3})?|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})| # United Kingdom
                    (?:HU)[0-9]{8}|                               # Hungary
                    (?:IE)[0-9]S[0-9]{5}L|                        # Ireland
                    (?:IT)[0-9]{11}|                              # Italy
                    (?:LT)(?:[0-9]{9}|[0-9]{12})|                 # Lithuania
                    (?:LU)[0-9]{8}|                               # Luxembourg
                    (?:LV)[0-9]{11}|                              # Latvia
                    (?:MT)[0-9]{8}|                               # Malta
                    (?:NL)[0-9]{9}B[0-9]{2}|                      # Netherlands
                    (?:PL)[0-9]{10}|                              # Poland
                    (?:PT)[0-9]{9}|                               # Portugal
                    (?:RO)[0-9]{2,10}|                            # Romania
                    (?:SE)[0-9]{12}|                              # Sweden
                    (?:SI)[0-9]{8}|                               # Slovenia
                    (?:SK)[0-9]{10}                               # Slovakia
                )\b""",
        flags=re.I | re.VERBOSE,
    )

response = requests.get('https://www.petch.fr/policies/legal-notice')
regex.findall(response.text)
```

Comment: Hello! Please provide a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly modified the `vat_regex2` pattern. Added case-insensitive flag and verbose flag (because of `#` comments). Also converted the capturing groups to non-capturing `(?: ...)` and put word-boundaries `\b` around:

```py
import re
import requests

url = "https://www.petch.fr/policies/legal-notice"
html = requests.get(url).text

vat_regex2 = re.compile(
    r"""\b(
                (?:AT)U[0-9]{8}|                              # Austria
                (?:BE)0[0-9]{9}|                              # Belgium
                (?:BG)[0-9]{9,10}|                            # Bulgaria
                (?:CY)[0-9]{8}L|                              # Cyprus
                (?:CZ)[0-9]{8,10}|                            # Czech Republic
                (?:DE)[0-9]{9}|                               # Germany
                (?:DK)[0-9]{8}|                               # Denmark
                (?:EE)[0-9]{9}|                               # Estonia
                (?:EL|GR)[0-9]{9}|                            # Greece
                (?:ES)[0-9A-Z][0-9]{7}[0-9A-Z]|               # Spain
                (?:FI)[0-9]{8}|                               # Finland
                (?:FR)[0-9A-Z]{2}[0-9]{9}|                    # France
                (?:GB)(?:[0-9]{9}(?:[0-9]{3})?|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})| # United Kingdom
                (?:HU)[0-9]{8}|                               # Hungary
                (?:IE)[0-9]S[0-9]{5}L|                        # Ireland
                (?:IT)[0-9]{11}|                              # Italy
                (?:LT)(?:[0-9]{9}|[0-9]{12})|                 # Lithuania
                (?:LU)[0-9]{8}|                               # Luxembourg
                (?:LV)[0-9]{11}|                              # Latvia
                (?:MT)[0-9]{8}|                               # Malta
                (?:NL)[0-9]{9}B[0-9]{2}|                      # Netherlands
                (?:PL)[0-9]{10}|                              # Poland
                (?:PT)[0-9]{9}|                               # Portugal
                (?:RO)[0-9]{2,10}|                            # Romania
                (?:SE)[0-9]{12}|                              # Sweden
                (?:SI)[0-9]{8}|                               # Slovenia
                (?:SK)[0-9]{10}                               # Slovakia
            )\b""",
    flags=re.I | re.VERBOSE,
)

print(vat_regex2.findall(html))
```

Prints:

```
['FR79852457621']
```

Comment: It worked for FR & NL targets so far. I'm testing other targets and found this one not being matched : https://www.wienzufuss.at/impressum/. There is a whitespace so I replace(' ','') in the string target. We should find the VAT number : ATU66917857

Comment: As it might be complicated to handle possible whitespaces in VAT numbers of each target (each site format them as they want), I remove all whitespaces and removed word boundaries. Still testing but seems to work properly for now

Comment: @IndiaSke - did you get a final working version? It would be awesome if you could share it!